# Scrapy Install / Version Error

Tags: python, scrapy

Just installed Scrapy and Looking for Installing Portia UI for Scrapy on Python 2.7.6 (32 bit)  Windows 7 (64 bit) with connectivity to IPv4 DNS Internet Service.

Getting following output error when version check is done.

```
C\> scrapy version 
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity
module: 'No module named service_identity'.  Please install it from <https://pyp
i.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are sa
tisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to s
upport it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification
.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
Scrapy 0.22.2
```

The project can be created but Scrapy seems non responsive to the Spiders as well.

The Scrapy installation is with all Win32 versions of in the order described on the Scrapy Site http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html and wherever required pip install or easy_install.

How shall I go about clearing the problem?

Comment: Did you install pyOpenSSL?

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, Yes all installations are done and working. The answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
pip install service_identity
```

Comment: Hi Jimbo Many Thanks It worked. I didn't know I had to tick it.