# python No module named service_identity

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I tried to update scrapy and when I tried to check the version I got the following error

```
C:\Windows\system32>scrapy version -v
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity
module: 'No module named service_identity'.  Please install it from <https://pyp
i.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are sa
tisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to s
upport it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification
.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
Scrapy  : 0.22.2
lxml    : 3.2.3.0
libxml2 : 2.9.0
Twisted : 14.0.0
Python  : 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
```

what is that please and how to solve it ?

I am using windows 7

Comment: @LieRyan for god sake, how could it be duplicated ? please try to think

Comment: How to quickly gain reps in StackOverflow, ask this same question for every single packages that exists in Python. The error message describes very clearly what the problem is and how to rectify it, you should read and try to understand what error messages you received before asking questions in SO. This questions shows no attempt to do even that.

Comment: @LieRyan how could I know that service_identity is a python package ? I though that it is a service in Windows

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli: You shouldn't have stopped reading after the word "service". If you continue reading the error message you'll find a clear link to the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org).

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli totally this is a dupe.

Comment: actual duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959336/scrapy-install-version-error

Comment: I had same problem on OSX 10.09, so it is not just on windows.

Comment: so why isn't this a dependency?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
pip install service_identity
```

It is complaining that you do not have `service_identity`.

More information on the module can be found [here on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity)

---

Note that this is a rather unusual scenario, because `service_identity` is not a requirement of the `twisted` package, whose developers for some reason chose not to add it to its list of dependencies (cf. [`pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/pyproject.toml#L32)), instead raising `UserWarning` about lack of this package, and requiring a manual intervention to fix.

Comment: It still get about the same *warning* (not an error, @Marco) message despite having it installed. Only the first phrase differs a little, probably because I'm running on mac. It says: `UserWarning: You do not have the service_identity module installed.` But when I run `pip install service_identity` (again) I get `Requirement already satisfied`. :(

Comment: @Cawas I was getting the same warning. It's funny but looks like service_identity didn't install it's dependencies. I had to `pip install pyasn1 characteristic` to get it to work on the Mac. That fixed the warning.

Comment: @Cawas try `sudo easy_install service_identity`

Comment: I had to use `pip install service_identity --force` to solve the issue

Comment: This one didn't work for me but because using anaconda `conda install service_identity` fixed this error

Comment: For me `service_identity==21.1.0` needs `attrs==22.2.0`, I had `attrs==21.2.0` & it was failing with error `ModuleNoFoundError attrs`

Comment: Make sure you install service_identity with service_identity==21.1.0 (or whatever the most recent version here https://service-identity.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html is). I got this error because I had version 18 instead of 21.